# SQL Server - Query by Geometry Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

Say I have following data in table `addresses`:

```
physicalState    physicalPostalCode    geometry
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
     PA               15340            0xE6100000010CAC1C5A643B1354C02D431CEBE2264440
     OK               74576            0xE6100000010C7DD0B359F50158C079E9263108544140
     WV               26033            0xE6100000010CE8D9ACFA5C2554C0273108AC1CEA4340
     WV               26033            0xE6100000010C36AB3E575B2554C0C3D32B6519EA4340
```

I want to

```
select * 
from addresses 
where geometry = GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT (40.3038 -80.3005)', 4326)
```

Finding it very difficult to figure this out...

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting of the question @marc_s ! couldn't figure that out either....

Comment: Those coordinates and the fact that you're referencing things like postal codes suggests to me that you should be using the geography data type rather than geometry…

Comment: @BenThul Curious as to why that is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because latitude and longitude are not Cartesian coordinates (as geometry would imply) but rather degrees to the east or west of an arbitrary north/south line (in the case of longitude) or degrees north or south of the equator (in the case of latitude). But more to the point, the geography data type takes into account that the coordinates given are demarcated as laid out above and reference points on the Earth. While you can approximate that locally with Cartesian geometry, you'll get weird results with larger objects. Quick rule of thumb: if you can drive or fly there, it's geography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use method  [[STContains]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb933904%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
like this condition:

```
geometry.STContains(GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT (40.3038 -80.3005)', 4326))
```

Comment: @marc_s Although I'd like for Adam Silenko to receive credit for his answer, I would like to mark the text from my response as the "Answer" as it provides multiple examples for others that may run into this same issue. How do I achieve this, yet still give the proper credit to Adam?

Comment: @FernandoVega: you should **upvote** Adam's answer (if you haven't already) - but in the end, you can only mark *one* answer as the "solution" / accepted answer - either Adam's or your own ...

Answer (score 0):

OKIE! Figured this one out... One thing worth noting, x/y coordinates were flip flopped. That helped to frustrate things. stupid me.

Either way, this is what in order able to query the database by specific points:

```
select * from addresses
WHERE geometry.ToString() = 'POINT (-80.3005 40.3038)'
```

Also, to credit @Adam Silenko, his solution also works as such:

```
select * 
from addresses
where geometry.STContains(GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT (-80.3005 40.3038)', 4326)) = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear about what you are doing:  When you call the ToString() method  you are now working with a string and not a geography data type.  Your query converts the point geometry to a string and then compares it to the string you gave i.e. 'Point (-80.3005 40.3038)'.  What @AdamSilenko suggested was to see if the geometry represented by that string was contained by any of the geometries in the addresses table.  These are different things.  To look for a 1 to 1 comparison of geometries, you should use the .STEquals() method.

Comment: @hcaelxxam thanks for the additional input! I definitely understand the concept and for this particular exercise, Either of the methods (ToString, STContains, STEquals) were sufficient to satisfy the requirement. Very good that you have included this along in the post for the informational value!! Thank you all for your assistance! -cheers